# Waiting for targets in a CMake build

Tags: cmake, build, ninja

I think I do have a CMake order/parallelism problem.

In my build process, I need to build a tool which is then later used by some other target. This tool is a separate project with a CMakeLists.txt file like this:

```
project (package-tool LANGUAGES CXX)
set (SOURCES package_tool.cpp)
...
```

Later in the build, this top level target is referenced by some other target:

```
...
add_custom_command (OUTPUT "${DST_FILE}"
                            COMMAND ${PACKAGE_COMMAND} "${DST_FILE}"
                            COMMAND package-tool.exe -e "${DST_FILE}"
                            DEPENDS ${PACKAGE_DEPENDENCIES} package-tool)
...
```

I use ninja for building and the dependencies (ninja -t depends) are looking correctly. Also, the build commands (ninja -t commands) are making sense. But: From time to time, the build fails. The message does not make sense, it reads:

> This version of package-tool.exe is not compatible with the version
> of Windows you're running.

Because the build runs in parallel (32 processes) I suspect that the package-tool target is not completed when the generated exe is being used in the second target, which might lead to this confusing error message. Again, most of the time the build succeeds but every 10th or 20th run, it fails with that message.

So now my question is:

- Is there a way to wait for a tool/target having been finished building in a parallel build in CMake/Ninja ?
- Or how do I handle the task of building build tools in the same build process correctly ?

Thank you in advance !

Comment: "I suspect that the package-tool target is not completed when the generated exe is being used in the second target" - As you say, `ninja` outputs dependencies as you expect. So, do you suspecting ninja to not follow these dependencies? Then the question should be not about CMake and writing `CMakeLists.txt`, but about ninja and its wrong behavior. It could be that a reason of the error you got is **somewhere else**.  But we could only **guess** about that, and *guessing* is not how Stack Overflow works.

Comment: Hmm... I think you are right. It does not make sense that CMake handles the concurrency, ninja should do that. Rethinking that, I would assume that a ninja step simply waits until the files it depends on are all present, so another cause for that problem outside of the CMake/Ninja domain does probably exist. Thank you for the insight !

Answer (score 2):

Actually depend on the executable file and run the executable file, not the target. Don't concern yourself with any `.exe` suffix. Also better don't assume `add_custom_command` will be run in `CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY` - if you depend on specific directory explicitly set it with `WORKING_DIRECTORY`.

```
add_custom_command (
    OUTPUT "${DST_FILE}"
    COMMAND ${PACKAGE_COMMAND} "${DST_FILE}"
    COMMAND $<TARGET_FILE:package-tool> -e "${DST_FILE}"
    DEPENDS ${PACKAGE_DEPENDENCIES} $<TARGET_FILE:package-tool>
)
```

Comment: Instead of `$<TARGET_FILE:package-tool>` CMake allows to specify just a target name:  `COMMAND package-tool -e "${DST_FILE}"`. Also, with both ways - `TARGET_FILE` or simply target name - CMake automatically adds a **target**-level dependency from the `package-tool`. It is up to the project whether a  **file**-level dependency from `package-tool` is needed or not. Such *file*-level dependency would only force custom command (more precisely, a custom target which depends on the command) to be re-run whenever the executable is changed.